# Making Multiquery for FQL having quotation issue

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-fql

I am integrating facebook with my native android app. I have to pass two queries together and I know this can be done by multiquery in FQL. I am putting my two queries those are need to convert into multiquery.

```
I have already taken a reference of 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/run-fql-queries/
```

Queries : -

```
query 1:SELECT id, text, time, fromid, likes,post_id FROM comment WHERE post_id IN('1274243354_10202683234503386')

query 2 : SELECT uid,pic,name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT fromid FROM comment WHERE post_id IN('1274243354_10202683234503386'))
```

I am trying above queries as multiquery and got the result

multiquery

```
String postID = "\'" + "1274243354_10202683234503386" + "\'";
        String query1 = "'SELECT post_fbid, fromid, text, time FROM comment WHERE post_id IN (" + postID + ")'";
        String query2 = "'SELECT id, name, url, pic FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT fromid FROM #query1)'";

    String fqlQuery = "{" +
            "'query1':" + query1 + "," +
            "'query2':" + query2 +
            "}";
```

Result of the multiquery

```
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 601, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#601) Parser error: unexpected '{' at position 0.}, isFromCache:false}
```

where I am making mistake? I can't get it ..

Comment: which data you want to get??

Comment: i want the data regarding who comment on the specific post. Like name,profiile pic and time ,text how many likes

Comment: http://graph.facebook.com/postid

Comment: but how can I use it with native android app. I have to use FQL for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'` marks the end of the query:

```
'SELECT post_fbid, fromid, text, time FROM comment WHERE post_id IN ('
```

So,

```
String postID = "\'" + "1274243354_10202683234503386" + "\'";
```

should be:

```
String postID = "\"" + "1274243354_10202683234503386" + "\"";
```

Comment: yeah i will try and let u know